# Help on Deep Sarsa algorithm that work with pytorch (Adam optimiser) but not with keras/Tensorflow (Adam optimiser)

Tags: deep-rl, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, sarsa

I have a deep sarsa algorithm wich work great on Pytorch on lunar-lander-v2 and I would use with Keras/Tensorflow. It use mini-batch of size 64 wich are used 128 time to train at each episode.

There are the results I get. As you can see, it work gread with Pytorch but not with Keras / Tensorflow... So I think I do not correctly implement the training function is Keras/Tensorflow (code is below).

It seems that loss is oscillating in Keras because epsilon go to early to slow value but it work very great in Pytorch...

Do you see something that could explain why it do not work in Keras/Tensorflow please ? Thanks a lot for your help and any idea that could help me ...

[image]

**Network informations:**

It use Adam optimizer, and a network with two layers : 256 and 128, with relu on each :

```
class Q_Network(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, state_dim , action_dim):
    super(Q_Network, self).__init__()
    self.x_layer = nn.Linear(state_dim, 256)
    self.h_layer = nn.Linear(256, 128)
    self.y_layer = nn.Linear(128, action_dim)
    print(self.x_layer)

def forward(self, state):
    xh = F.relu(self.x_layer(state))
    hh = F.relu(self.h_layer(xh))
    state_action_values = self.y_layer(hh)
    return state_action_values
```

For keras/Tensorflwo I use this one :

```
def CreationModele(dimension): 
  entree_etat = keras.layers.Input(shape=(dimension))

  sortie = keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu')(entree_etat)
  sortie = keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(sortie)
  sortie = keras.layers.Dense(units=4)(sortie)

  modele = keras.Model(inputs=entree_etat,outputs=sortie)
  return modele
```

**Training code**

In Pytorch, the training is done by :

```
def update_Sarsa_Network(self, state, next_state, action, next_action, reward, ends):

    actions_values = torch.gather(self.qnet(state), dim=1, index=action.long())

    next_actions_values = torch.gather(self.qnet(next_state), dim=1, index=next_action.long())

    next_actions_values = reward + (1.0 - ends) * (self.discount_factor * next_actions_values)

    q_network_loss = self.MSELoss_function(actions_values, next_actions_values.detach())
    self.qnet_optim.zero_grad()
    q_network_loss.backward()
    self.qnet_optim.step()
    return q_network_loss
```

And in Keras/Tensorflow by :

```
mse = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(
    reduction=keras.losses.Reduction.SUM)

@tf.function
def train(model, batch_next_states_tensor, batch_next_actions_tensor, batch_reward_tensor, batch_end_tensor, batch_states_tensor, batch_actions_tensor, optimizer, gamma):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # EStimation des valeurs des actions courantes
    actions_values = model(batch_states_tensor)                                                          # (mini_batch_size,4)
    actions_values = tf.linalg.diag_part(tf.gather(actions_values,batch_actions_tensor,axis=1))         # (mini_batch_size,)
    actions_values = tf.expand_dims(actions_values,-1)                                                  # (mini_batch_size,1)

    # EStimation des valeurs des actions suivantes
    next_actions_values = model(batch_next_states_tensor)                                                          # (mini_batch_size,4)
    next_actions_values = tf.linalg.diag_part(tf.gather(next_actions_values,batch_next_actions_tensor,axis=1))   # (mini_batch_size,)
    cibles = batch_reward_tensor + (1.0 - batch_end_tensor)*gamma*tf.expand_dims(next_actions_values,-1)         # (mini_batch_size,1)

    error = mse(cibles, actions_values)
    
  grads = tape.gradient(error, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
  
  return error
```

**Error function and Optimizer code**

The optimizer is Adam in Pytorch and Tensorflow with lr=0.001. In Pytorch :

```
def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim):
    self.qnet = Q_Network(state_dim, action_dim)
    self.qnet_optim = torch.optim.Adam(self.qnet.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    self.discount_factor = 0.99
    self.MSELoss_function = nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
    self.replay_buffer = ReplayBuffer()
    pass
```

In Keras / Tensorflow:

```
alpha = 1e-3

# Initialise le modèle
modele_Keras = CreationModele(8)

optimiseur_Keras = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=alpha)
```

Comment: Ok I finaly foud a solution by de-correlate target and action value using two model, one being updated periodically for target values calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finnaly foud a solution by de-correlate target and action value using two model, one being updated periodically for target values calculation.

I use a model for estimating the epsilon-greedy actions and computing the Q(s,a) values and a fixed model (but periodically uptated with the weight of the previous model) for calculate the targer r+gamma*Q(s',a').

Here is my result :
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Would you share new output image like in your question?

Comment: yes I just edited my previous post